# Setting up a webhook on AWS - node.js APP

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, webhooks

I set up a node.js app and deployed it onto elastic beanstalk. I need to create webhook so that the app can listen to a typeform survey. What is the best way to do this? Should I use a lambda? Is there a way to do this on elastic beanstalk?

Comment: A webhook is just a HTTP listener endpoint with logic to handle the payload. There's nothing preventing you from using beanstalk for your webhook,

Answer (score 0):

Elastic beanstalk supports a lot of different programming languages such as Node.js, Rails or PHP.

In Node.js you can probably rely on the [Express](https://expressjs.com/) framework to create a simple HTTP route and listen to webhooks event.

```js
app.post('/typeform/webhook', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }),(request, response) => {
  
  // security check, let's make sure request comes from typeform
  const signature = request.headers['typeform-signature']
  const isValid = verifySignature(signature, request.body.toString())

  if (!isValid) {
    throw new Error('Webhook signature is not valid, someone is faking this!');  
  }

  // send 200 status back, and notifies typeform 
  response.sendStatus(200)

  const { event_type, form_response } = JSON.parse(request.body);

  // filter response events only
  if (event_type === 'form_response') {
    // extract answers for example get email from ref
    const email_addr = form_response.answers.find(a => a.field.type === 'email').email
  }
});
```

The `verifySignature` function is optional but adds security as it verifies if the payload received comes from Typeform.

```js
// function to verify request signature comes from Typeform
const verifySignature = function(receivedSignature, payload){
  const hash = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', process.env.TYPEFORM_WEBHOOK_SECRET)
    .update(payload)
    .digest('base64')
  return receivedSignature === `sha256=${hash}`
}
```

Once you have this express app setup you can deploy it into Elastic beanstalk.